# How to build in superpower game engine browser?

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I have downloaded and build superpower game engine from github.It runs on a local host in browser.But there is no option to publish.How come i publish a game in it.

Comment: Where would you like to publish it?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation, there is a section `PUBLISHING YOUR GAME`.

http://docs.superpowers-html5.com/en/getting-started/publishing-your-game

But as they state :

> Exporting is only available from the app, not when accessing
>   Superpowers through the browser, because browsers do not let Web apps
>   access the filesystem directly for security reasons.

So you will have to open your project from the app and not from the localhost website.